# Return array by reference in C#3.5

Tags: c#-3.0

Since C# 3.5 doesn't have the ref keyword, (unless it does and I'm missing something) I figured that a very hacky workaround would be to use pointers like so.

```
public unsafe uint toByteArray() {
    byte[] arr = new byte[10];
    return (uint)&arr;
}
```

I could then uncast/reference it later. But this seems leaky. Furthermore, I *really* don't want to copy the array, because there's no way I'm going to be editing it; I just want a reference to read from. Is there any sane way doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need a reference in this case

```
public byte[] toByteArray()
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[10];
    ...
    return arr;
}
```

Returns a reference to the created array and does not copy anything since arrays are reference types in .net.

Returning by reference (ref return values) is not the same thing as returning a reference type instance.

Comment: This makes sense. I couldn't find this information in the documentation anywhere. Thanks!